# consider the function $d_i(\omega)=i$-th bit of the non-terminating binary expansion of $\omega$.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

consider the function $d_i(\omega)=i$-th bit of the non-terminating binary expansion of $\omega$. Is $d_i:\Bbb R -> \Bbb R$ measurable ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: it is constant on intervals

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What is the set of real numbers with a $1$ after the comma? Is it measurable? Try to generalize the argument.